# ValueError: special directives must be the first entry

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

why this error appears and what does it mean exactly?

It appears on this code (I put only the part of machine learning, because the code is so long):

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import neighbors
n_neighbors = 3

if (automatic == 'true'):
    # import some data to play with
    home = Homes.query.filter_by(device_id = request.args.get('?device_id')).first()

    htng_orders = Heating_orders.query.filter_by(home_id = home.id).all()

    X_h = [[ho.timeInMinutes, ho.season, ho.ext_temp] for ho in htng_orders]
    y_h = [ho.instruction for ho in htng_orders] 

    clf_h = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors, weights='distance')
    clf_h.fit(X_h, y_h)

    new_time = datetime.datetime.now().time()
    new_timeInMinutes = (new_time.hour*60 + new_time.minute)
    new_season = get_season(date.today())
    new_ext_temp = getExtTemperature(home.city)
    new_data_h = np.c_[new_timeInMinutes, new_season, new_ext_temp]
    preddiction_h = clf_h.predict(new_data_h)
```

The error is the following:

```
[...]

File "C:\[...]\FlaskREST\app.py", line 525, in get
    new_data_h = np.c_[new_timeInMinutes, new_season, new_ext_temp]
File "C:\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 289, in __getitem__
    raise ValueError("special directives must be the "
ValueError: special directives must be the first entry.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which are the special directives?

Comment: Can you show us `type(new_timeInMinutes)`, `type(new_season)` and `type(new_ext_temp)`?

Comment: The error is coming from `np.c_[...]`.  A simple example that reproduces the error is `np.c_[1, 'foo']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at what the code is doing I don't think you should have `np.c_` there at all. The model is trained on a triplets of `(TimeInMinutes, season, ext_temp)`, so you'll want to pass that same data format into the `.predict` function.

`new_data_h` should be

```
new_data_h = [new_timeInMinutes, new_season, new_ext_temp]
```

---

just in case you're curious

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html

Comment: Thank you! In fact, `new_data_h` has to be:
    `new_data_h = [[new_timeInMinutes, new_season, new_ext_temp]]`

Comment: Because if not, there is an error like this: `ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=['1345' '1' '13.0'].`

Answer (score 0):

i was also getting the same issue, ValueError: special directives must be the from numpy  index_tricks.py file. This error was coming when i was passing wrong parameter types to sarimax.

After correcting the parameter types, this error was resolved. check from this scenario, it may help.